# How to correctly align left in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an opening hours section and I would like to align my days on the left side of the table. I tried `float: left;` but my Monday gets sent a few pixels above. text-align: left; did not work, can anyone suggest a correct way I can align my days?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQYQv.jpg (as you can see my Monday is skewed)

CSS

```
 .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
 .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:2px 10px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal; text-align:right;border-style: solid;border-bottom: solid #E7E7E7 1px;}
.day { float: left; }
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:2px 10px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal; text-align:right;color:#696969;border-style: solid;border-bottom: solid #E7E7E7 1px;}
.tg .tg-57v2{background-color:#f7f7f7}
```

HTML

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
<th class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Monday</span></th>
<th class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Tuesday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Wednesday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Thursday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Friday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Saturday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-57v2"><span class="day">Sunday</span></td>
<td class="tg-57v2">                           11:30am-10:00pm</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think `float:left` will work on a table.  Are you open to using `div` elements?

Comment: Looks ok ? https://jsfiddle.net/80cerupu/

Comment: I was going to add a jsfiddle but it looks different on my site. @steveklein I am open -- should I be doing a div class="day" instead of span?

Comment: Remove `text-align: right` from your css and look at the answer below.

Comment: Did you see my answer?  I am guessing that will fix your current problem.  I do encourage you to start thinking in terms of `div`s and possibly look at `Bootstrap` (http://getbootstrap.com/).  It is really easy to use and you get a responsive site that way.

Comment: Don't just think `divs`, think semantic. You have a list of opening times ordered by date, perhaps a `ol` would be more appropriate or even a  `dl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monday is styled as a `th` (header).  If you change it to a `td` like the other days, it should align.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed -- didn't notice it was a header. I'll vote this best answer soon. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Potentially a more semantic approach with a lot less markup:

```css
dl.OpenHours {width:300px; }

dl.OpenHours>*{
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:2px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
    text-align:right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: solid #E7E7E7 1px;
    float:left;    
    margin:0;
 }

dl.OpenHours dt
{
    width:30%;
    text-align:left;
    border-right-width:2px;
}

dl.OpenHours dd
{
  width:50%;  
  border-left-width:0;
}
```

```html
<dl class="OpenHours">
       <dt>Monday</dt>
       <dd>10:00am - 11:00pm</dd>
      <dt>Tuesday</dt>
       <dd>10:00am - 11:00pm</dd>
      <dt>Wednessday</dt>
       <dd>10:00am - 11:00pm</dd>
      <dt>Thursday</dt>
       <dd>10:00am - 11:00pm</dd>
      <dt>Friday</dt>
       <dd>10:00am - 11:00pm</dd>
    </dl>
```